# Convert an image into digits with PHP?

Tags: php, image

I am trying to figure out how I can convert a `color image` into numbers.

For example, if I have an image like the one shown in `figure (b)`, how can I get a output like `figure (a)` in to a text file?

[image]

Comment: Now you are talking about gray level image, if you want to do that to a colored image each pixel would have 3 numbers from 0 to 255. (red: 0-255, green: 0-255, blue : 0-255)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php It could be googled easily with "php image read pixel color" if you gave google a try

Comment: Could you share the actual image with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took what was in [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php#71444) which Mehdi Karamosly mentioned in his answer and modified it some to be a little bit simipiler and made a simple html output which you can modify to your outputs liking. You might want to add more data checking to make sure its a file/real image if you are looking to add security. I've checked it out on my computer and it works and hopefully it will work for what you need with some modification(s).

```
function graycolor($img){
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img);
    $mime = pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    switch($mime){#use appropriate function depending on image type
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
            break;
        case 'png':
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($img);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $im = imagecreatefromgif($img);
            break;
        default:
            #invalid type
            exit;
    }
    if(!is_color($img, $im)){#$img = string; $im = resource string
        $ret = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < $height; $i++){#loop height pixels
            for($ii = 0; $ii < $width; $ii++){#loop width pixels
                $color = imagecolorat($im, $ii, $i);
                $color = imagecolorsforindex($im, $color);
                $ret .= $color['red'] . " ";
            }
                $ret .= "\n";
        }
        return $ret;
    }else{
        #$ret = "";
        #for($i = 0; $i < $height; $i++){#loop height pixels
            #for($ii = 0; $ii < $width; $ii++){#loop width pixels
                #$color = imagecolorat($im, $ii, $i);
                #$color = imagecolorsforindex($im, $color);
                #$ret .= $color['red'] . ", " . $color['green'] . ", " . $color['blue'] . " ";
            #}
                #$ret .= "\n";
        #}
        return "color image";
    }

}
function is_color($img, $im){
    $times = 10;#number of times to check image for color
    $iscolor = false;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img);
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $times && !$iscolor; $i++){
        $color = imagecolorat($im, rand(0, $width), rand(0, $height));#get random cords
        $color = imagecolorsforindex($im, $color);#get the random color's values
        if($color['red'] !== $color['green'] || $color['green'] !== $color['blue']){
            $iscolor = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $iscolor;
}

echo graycolor('color.jpg');#outputs color image
echo graycolor('gray.jpg');#outputs numbers
```

Comment: thank you so much for explaining it to me with a detailed example. that helped a lot.

Comment: @Class that's a nice explanation. but this does not convert a color image in to numbers. Can you please tell us how to convert a color image in to number as well?

Comment: @NewGuy I've added a how to get color numbers which will give you `r, g, b` and you can search on SO for ways if you want the number in some other format.

Answer (score 2):

Now you are talking about gray level image, if you want to do that to a colored image each pixel would have 3 numbers from 0 to 255. (red: 0-255, green: 0-255, blue : 0-255)

If you are interested in grey scale image one important rule you would need to know is :

> // A Pixel is Greyscale if the r = B = G

based on this [post](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php#71444).

Take a look at this php function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php